# How to make back-end data return to front-end automatically when back-end data change with springMvc?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

I am developing a software with springMvc. A new feature is I should get state of some devices in JSP. These devices will do some tasks in back-end. And it will take some time to do that. During this time, I `d like to make task state return to front-end in real time.
How can I implement it?

Comment: you might want to check socket connections

Comment: That is [useful](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/)

Comment: You can use event based programming.